# Hide or disable node fields

Tags: 6

I am using drupal 6 and i have created my own content type and few CCK fields. When user is creating a node, i don't want to show him fields like menu settings, revison information, and many others, is it possible in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The access to menu settings/revision information, etc. is controlled by permissions. For example the user will require 'administer menu' permission in order to choose what menus their content will go in.

You just need to find the permissions the relate to whatever task you're trying to deny access to, and make sure the users in question don't have that permission (at http://mysite.com/admin/user/permissions).

Failing that, you should use a [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) function in a custom module, and set the field/fieldset [`#access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#access) to `FALSE`:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_form_id') {
    $form['the_field']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

In case you need to control access to certain CCK fields that you've created, the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module is available for Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 and will do just that.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Comment: very good solution . upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 modules that I found that seem to do similar tricks.

Jammer 
https://www.drupal.org/project/formfilter

FormFilter 
https://www.drupal.org/project/jammer